# How to reference variable I can access from console in firefox extension code?

Tags: javascript, console, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm currently working on a firefox extension for a specific trusted website. I would like access to a variable "ownUsername" that I can access from the console. However, I am unable to access this variable from my extension code, and cannot find it inside the window object. How would I go about accomplishing this?

I've tried digging around in dev tools and think I found the function where the variable is defined, but I don't understand how I can call it from the console when it seems like a local variable. Unfortunately I am unable to share any of the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the variable defined? If it's declared with `let` or `const`, it doesn't get added to `window`.

Comment: Have a look at content script.

Comment: @Barmar it is declared with const. is there any way to access it or am i wasting my time?